# Ubuntu Server without GUI on an Azure XS virtual machine

Tags: multithreading, azure, virtual-machine

I will be running ubuntu server without GUI with a small application written in c that communicates with other XS machines and my home computer over TCP, but i am confused about one thing my application has 2 threads one that does the processing and one that handles the TCP messages, they only mention that the XS is equivalent to a 64-bit 1GHz processor, does that mean a single core with 2 threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from running a multi-threaded application on a single CPU.

Some details: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116952/can-multithreading-be-implemented-on-a-single-processor-system)